# Report data not showing in embedded API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I set up the OAuth 2.0 client ID, copied and pasted the code to embed Basic Dashboard of Google Analytics API from https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

However, in my localhost server, I see the "Access Google Analytics" button, when clicked and given authorization, it displays nothing but "You are logged in as: xxxxx@gmail.com".
Isn't supposed to display charts and/or reporting data below the text, as it's seen in Google Analytics Embed API Overview document?:

[image: google's default screenshot of embedded api]

And here it is my actual content:

[image: missing charts below the text]

Here it is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->

<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>

<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>


<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
   * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
   * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'my client code'
  });


  /**
   * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "view-selector-container".
   */
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector-container'
  });

  // Render the view selector to the page.
  viewSelector.execute();


  /**
   * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
   * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
   * with the id "chart-container".
   */
  var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  });


  /**
   * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
   */
  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
  });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: One problem could be is that *xxx@gmail.com* does not have any Google Analytics Accounts. If you log in as the same user to the [Demo's and Tools Embed API Application](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/) do you see any results?

Comment: @Matt, yes, when I login in demo embed API application, it works. I can see the reporting data of my associated website.

Comment: Found one issue; see my Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `viewSelector.execute()` once the authentication is successful. As you have now it only gets called the first time through:

#### Replace

```
// Render the view selector to the page.
viewSelector.execute();
```

### with:

```
// Render the view selector once user is authenticated.
gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
  viewSelector.execute();
});
```

Comment: Hmmm.. it's still the same. After giving permission, only my e-mail appears.